Every PID that is not a field, and has a finite number of units, has an infinite number of non-associate irreducible elements
I am trying to make a research and prove this claim; and I proved it; it is a mimic or extending to Furstenberg's proof of infinite primes in $\mathbb{Z}$, I want to know if the claim is true or not, and in both cases, does my proof has any mistakes?

Sketch for my proof:
Let $R$ to be an infinite PID but not a field, and has finite number of units, $I$ stands for ideal, and define the following topology: $\mathscr{T}= \{U: a \in U \implies a+I \subseteq U, \text{ for some } I \subseteq R, I \neq \{0\}\} \cup \{\varnothing \}$, and every set of the form $a+I$ is open and closed simultaneously (clopen), another one that is each open set is infinite.
Let $\{0+I_i: I_i \text{ is an ideal of } R\}$ be the family of all ideal except for $R$, each one of them is closed, if they are finite, the union must be closed.
Assumption: $R \setminus \{u: \text{ u is a unit in } R\} = \bigcup\limits_{I_i\text{ ideal }} I_i$.
Proof:
Let $a \in R \backslash \{u: \text{ u is a unit in } R\} $, $a$ is either an irreducible or can be written as a product of irreducible, in both cases there exists an ideal that contain $a$, then $a \in \bigcup I_i$. Now assume that $\exists u \in \bigcup I_i$ such that $u$ is a unit, then $u \in I_i$ for some ideal $I_i$, then $I_i = R$, which is a contradiction.
Then $\bigcup I_i = R\backslash \{u: \text{ u is a unit in } R\}$, which is a union of closed sets, however it is not closed, because its complement $\{u: \text{ u is a unit in } R\}$ is finite and not open.

What if $R$ is an infinite field? This does not satisfy either of your conditions.

Let's assume that it is not a field, because fields has only two ideals the trivial ideal and the field itself, I will edit the question to let R just an integral domain, and see if it solves the problem.

@Exct Please put that assumption into the question body itself using the edit button.

"This claim". There is no claim. Posts don't begin in the title, the body should be self-contained and complete.

Your description of $\mathscr{T}$ is not correctly formed. You introduce $I$, then you quantify existentially over $I$. As written, it is incoherent.

I will edit the question to let R just an integral domain - no, you did not. See your title.

And you do not specify if you are talking about an infinite number of non-associate irreducibles, or if you want to count associated irreducibles as distinct.

I meant an PID that is just a integral domain and not a field

@Exct Your post still doesn't say this. Any field is a PID, and any PID is an integral domain. You have to explicitly say that you want $R$ to be a PID but not a field (and you can drop "integral domain" entirely).

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Well I thought this site is meant to help mathematician and mathematics students to understand mathematics more and question things about mathematics.
Anyway I am trying to make edits to this question to be a proper and "coherent" as possible.

There are too many things that don't make sense here. Your description of $\mathscr{T}$, as I already mentioned, is incoherent: is $I$ supposed to be fixed? If so, why is it quantified inside the description of $\mathscr{T}$? If not, then the formula inside the description of $\mathscr{T}$ is not well formed, as it uses $I$ before it is quantified. Second, you say a set of subsets is "open" and "closed"... but you never mention any topology (on the power set, also, since $\mathscr{T}$ is a set of sets). This is incoherent. And the statement you want to establish is false.

The proof works for any PID (or UFD) with finitely many units that is not a field. Of course, ${1_R, -1_R}$ must be replaced with the set of units of $R$.

As Geoffrey Trang pointed out, your idea of the proof is correct, but the statement is false (and the details are not accurate, for instance you should consider only prime ideals). It should read as "if a PID (or UFD, but then consider only cyclic prime ideals) has only finitely many units, and is not a field, then it has infinitely many, pairwise non-associated primes". And, indeed, I would consider this proof as very elegant. Therefore, I would be happy to vote for reopening, if you update the question (and title) accordingly, also taking into account the other comments.

Thank you very much for helping me!
I will consider your answer and make the changes when I am done with the details on paper.

No, this is not true in general. Consider a localisation $R_P$, where $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$. The (local) rings $R_P$ are examples of discrete valuation rings (DVRs), which all have just one irreducible element, up to unit multiples.
Also, referring to the possible edit that the ring is not a PID but just an integral domain, the infinite ring $\overline{\Bbb Z}$ of algebraic integers has no irreducible elements.

... but the ring of all algebraic integers is not a PID.

@ArturoMagidin The OP wanted to change the question to say that $R$ is just an integral domain (second comment).

It is unclear if "infinite number of irreducibles" implies "up to units" or not. The post needs a lot of clarification.

Yes, indeed, this is true.

Please do not answer off-topic questions (here a SV missing required context).
